# Filesystem input or output error?

Tags: php, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse PHP 3.0.2 and afterwards the RSE in order to be able to create a project based on a ftp connection, and work with remote files.

Although the user and pass are corect (i have tested it with another ftp program) i get this error.

[image: Ecplise RSE Error]

What is wrong? How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue in Eclipse related to which version of the JDK you are running. Remove all versions of Java and re-install the latest version.

Comment: I have installed last java env and ecplipse-php on a fresh virtual machine. Same error. Is there another way to create a projects which handles remote files?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out here that runing Java 6 "resolves" the problem. Shure this is not exactly what I need. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/874556/

I also tried another approach: using a web disk so project might look local. But when creating project using files from web disk drive eclipse crashed.. Seemed like "fetching" files never stops..